Inconsistent Line Thickness in Blender’s Line Art Animation
I’ve been experimenting with creating animations using 'Line art' in Blender. Despite my character being in a static pose, I’ve noticed that the thickness of the grease pencil lines varies. Previously, when I used Freestyle, this issue did not occur. (I’ve tried 'Line art' for the first time) I’m encountering this problem. Is there a way to maintain consistent thickness for static poses?

